# perf profiling in Linux

Tags: linux, profiling, perf

If I ask `perf list` to tell me what I can do, it says

```
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetches                                     [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-prefetch-misses                                [Hardware cache event]
```

However, if I ask `perf stat -eLLC-load-misses ls`, it tells me

```
   <not supported> LLC-load-misses         

       0,001647655 seconds time elapsed
```

Is it supported or not? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What architecture you are running this on?

Comment: I guess `perf list` gives you what the software `perf` can do with proper support from the hardware; with the second one you get what is actually supported on your machine. So, I think you don't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There could be various reasons why the counter is shows as "not supported"

Following are few of them

- You are running the perf on some Virtual hardware inside Virtual machine
- The architecture itself does not have such counter. You have to check the Architecture specs to find out if the counter is supported

P.S. if you see "not counted" it means you need to enable the kernel support for the counters. Which is not in your case.